# How to remove everything within <>

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string that looks kinda like:
`Approximately <b>Silver I</b><br><br><span class=symbol--micro></span>MMR resembles the <b>top 49%</b> of summoners in Silver I`

Problem is that I dont want anything within `<` and `>`. In an old code my solution was:

```py
summary = MMR_info["ranked"]["summary"]
summary = summary.replace('<b>', '')
summary = summary.replace('<br>', '')
summary = summary.replace('<span class="symbol--micro"></span>', ' ')
summary = summary.replace('</b>', '')
```

but this wasn't very pretty.
I would appreciate the how and why on doing this the most efficient way.

Comment: This is also the topic of one of the most notorious posts on the site: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1405065

Comment: Reason i asked was that my peanut brain could not make this way work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HTML parser such as `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'Approximately <b>Silver I</b><br><br><span class=symbol--micro></span>MMR resembles the <b>top 49%</b> of summoners in Silver I'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.text)
```

Output:

```
Approximately Silver IMMR resembles the top 49% of summoners in Silver I
```

Note that regular expressions are often suggested as a way to deal with HTML modification, but they usually become difficult to understand and maintain .

Comment: Sorry for making yet another such question, thank you for giving an answer simple enough for my peanut brain!